# How to prioritize express requests/responds over other intensive server related tasks

Tags: node.js, multithreading

My node application currently has two main modules:

- a scraper module
- an express server

The former is very server intensive task which indefinately runs in a loop. It scrapes information from over more than 100 urls, crunches the data and puts it into a mongodb database (using mongoose). This process runs over and over and over. :P

The latter part, my express server, responds to http/socket get requests and returns the crunched data which was written to the db by the scraper to the requesting client.

I'd like to optimize the performance of my server so that the express requests and responds get prioritized over the server intensive task(s). A client should be able to get the requested data asap, without having the scraper eat up all of my server resources.

I though about putting the server intensive task or the express server into its own thread, but then I stumbled upon `cluster`, and `child processes`; and now I'm totally confused which approach would be the right one for my situation.

One of the benefits I'm having is that there is a clear seperation between the writing part of my application and the reading part. The scraper writes stuff to the db, express reads from the db (no post/put/delete/...) calls are exposed. So, I -guess- I won't run into threading problems with different threads trying to write to the same db.

Any good suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is no threads in nodejs, you can emulate something approaching with child process. child process let you setup a communication between parent and child https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources like cpu and memory required by processes are managed by the operative system. You should not waste your time writing that logic within your source code.

I think you should look at the problem from outside your source code files. Once they ran they are processes. Processes are managed, as I said, by the OS.

Firstly I would split that on two separate commands.
One being the **scraper** module (eg `npm run scraper`, that runs something like `node scraper.js`).
The other one being your express server (eg `npm start`, that runs something like `node server.js`).

This approach will let you configure that within your OS or your cluster.

A rapid approach for that will be to use docker.

With two docker containers running your projects with cpu usage limitations. This is fairly easy to do and does not require for you to lift a new server... and at the same time it provides the
isolation level you need to scale it to many servers in the future.

Steps to do this:

- Learn a little about docker and docker compose and install them in your server
- Build a docker image for your application (you can upload it to a free private image that docker hub gives you for free)
- Build a docker compose for your two services using that image, with the cpu configuration you need (you can set both cpu and memory limits easily)

An alternative to that would be running the two commands (npm run **scraper** and npm start) with some tool like cpulimit, nice/niceness and ionice, or something else like namespaces and cgroups manually (but docker does that for you).

PD: Also, I would recommend to rethink your backend process. Maybe it's better to run it every 12 hours or something like that, instead of all the time, and you may run it from within cron instead of a loop.

Comment: Node is designed to rely on multiple processes not multiple threads for concurrent processing.  And since these two tasks have little to do with each other, separate VMs makes great sense.

Comment: However it is important to say that containers (docker) are not the same thing as VMs.